# Oracle exception messages raised on custom applications

Tags: c#, wpf, oracle, odp.net

The WPF application i'm coding uses Oracle 11.2.0.3 as DBMS and the odp 2.112.3.0.

When i launch it on my development VM and an exception PL\SQL is rised i get the complete message description along with the call stack. 
When i launch in the production environment i don't get any message than this:

```
ORA-20100: Message 20100 not found;  product=RDBMS; facility=ORA
```

Although the error code is the same in both cases the description is different(and in the latter case total useless).

the PL\SQL code rising the exception is this :

```
RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20100,'Order validation error, please retry later!');
```

if i turn off the distributed transaction(i.e. each transaction runs in its own scope) the exception message is raised correctly

There is no ODE call within the PL\SQL stored procedure.

Comment: What is the PL/SQL code throwing this?

Comment: This is the part which rises error. We need part where error is raised.

Comment: It seems like your database thinks you raised a positive numbered error. Check for typos, maybe you missed a minus sign in production?

Comment: @nvoigt: That was my idea too. Maybe the packages are out of version?

Comment: @PatrickHofman the database i use in the development and production environments  is exactly the same. Only the client is different(but i checked the loaded Oracle.DataAccess dll loaded by both processes and it's the same)

Comment: Maybe there is other place, where error is raised and looks kind of like this: RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20100,l_some_variable); or RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(l_that_err_nr,l_some_variable);

Comment: @DARK_A yes there are other places where i use a cursor variabile to compose the exception message, does it matter?

Comment: There is possibility that somewhere you forgot to assign message value to variable or somewhere assign NULL to message variable.

Comment: Or maybe cursor returns NULL

Comment: Can you find out if you are using "Oracle Database Extensions for .NET" to run .NET code as an external procedure on the database server? This error can occur when that there is a misconfiguration there. If you are not using that, then look for PL/SQL file io problems. Googling shows a lot of hits for FND_FILE failing.

Comment: @ChristianShay i actually use ODE but the error occurs when any PL\SQL stored procedures are called inside the .NET code(and obviously when exceptions are raised). I don't understand exactly why you suggest to check PL\SQL file IO problems.

Comment: Is this .NET code being loaded into the database and being called by SQL or PL/SQL (eg using ODE)? Or is it running in the middle tier or as a client? What happens if you call the same PL/SQL from SQLPlus (or from Visual Studio Query Window)? Is the Stored Proc you care calling using any PL/SQL file io related packages? (eg UTL FILE) Is the Stored Proc calling .NET code using ODE? We need a lot more info.

Comment: the .NET code is running as a client(specifically is a Windows NT service and a WPF application). No calls are sent from PL/SQL to .NET procedures, ODE is installed but in this scenario is not used.
If i call the same PL\SQL sp from  SQLPlus or SQLNavigator(i.e. without using odp.net but straight the OCI level) the exception message is raised correctly. The stored procedure doesn't call any ODE procedure or any file io package.

Comment: @ChristianShay another point to mention: if i turn off the distributed transaction(i.e. each transaction runs in its own scope) the exception message is raised correctly

Comment: OK. Do I understand correctly that your PL/SQL package is manually raising this exception? (eg your PL/SQL code is explicitly calling RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR? Are you passing in a constant text string for the error message or are you creating it using logic? (perhaps such logic is failing and you should use a PL/SQL debugger)

Comment: yes the PL\SQL package is raising an excepittion using the RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR istruction. I'm passing a constant text string as in the question example. If used a custom logic to compose the exception message why should it works when called from SQL/plus and shouldn't when called by .NET?

Comment: i see there is a well known bug in Oracle(16919404) but i find no solution for this in Google